# Very delayed IIS response from WCF service when returning fairly large data set

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I have an IIS 7 hosted WCF service that is mainly being used to return data through the entity framework. One of the operation contracts/service methods returns a list of roughly 17000 very simple and fairly small entity objects. The response size ends up being roughly 6.5MB so it's not huge. When I host the service on my development machine with IIS Express, the service call is made and the data is posted back promptly (within 10 seconds).  When I push the service to our server, the response takes an average of 1:46 seconds to come back.  After doing some tracing on the web server, I discovered that the method that fetches the data only takes 6 seconds to return. That being the case, the server is taking roughly 1:40 seconds to prepare and then send the response (which I've confirmed in the web logs so it's not a network latency issue).

These are the only configurations that I have in the service definition:

```
  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

This is what my web.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="RGDataBehavior" name="WCFData.Web.Services.DataAccess">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeBuffer" name="RGData_http" contract="WCFData.Web.Services.IDataAccess" listenUriMode="Explicit"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://myurl.com/Services/Data.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeBuffer"
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                 openTimeout="00:10:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                 transferMode="StreamedResponse"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"                 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RGDataBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceAuthorization
            serviceAuthorizationManagerType="WCFData.Web.Authentication.WCFAuthenticator,
                                             Data.Web.Authentication"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've been busting my head over this and most of what I've found doesn't quite seem to fit the bill so I would love some help if anyone has suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is more of a work around than a true solution to the problem. Changing the service method to return a byte array rather than a collection so that IIS wouldn't have to write an XML serialized collection into the response took care of the issue but it still doesn't explain why the delay was happening in the first place. I used the [protobuf-net library](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net) to serialize my return collection to a byte array and then again on the client side to deserialize the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend enabling [WCF trace logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) which might help get more timing numbers out of the WCF internals.

You could also, run the server through a profiling tool, and try to narrow down exactly what method is taking so long, but I'm not sure if there is a good way to do that through IIS.

If all else fails, you can always take some thread dumps while the server is processing (during this 1m40s processing time) and look at the stack trace for each thread to see what might be stuck. I usually do that using ntsd.exe command line debugger that installs with the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) package.

---

*Edit:*

Here is another idea.  Since you think it is related directly to the serialization, you can isolate the `DataContractSerializer` and time how long it takes to serialize your data. Code would look like:

```
[OperationContract]
public YourData[] YourServiceMethod()
{
    YourData[] data = ... // get all your data here as usual.

    // lets serialize it and time how long it takes
    var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    var dataContractSerializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(data.GetType());
    using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, data);
    }
    timer.Stop();

    System.Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds); // Log this, or whatever...

    // return now as normal (WCF will re-serialize, talking even longer, but this is just a test anyway)
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Any tips on getting WCF trace logging to work on the server side? I've got it going locally with IIS Express but when I push the web.config to the server, the trace log file doesn't write even after granting full control to the application pool identity account to the specified location.

Comment: Never-mind the follow-up question. Specifying a "initializeData" location outside of the web root and making sure that "Users" had modify rights took care of it. Now on to the logs.

Comment: @Ryan - yeah I always forget about log directory permissions when I set up a new server too :)

Comment: Well, the WCF trace log looks fine to me. I don't see any delays at all there. I enabled tracing under system.web also in the web.config but the generated trace.axd didn't really give me much as far as IIS itself goes. As an experiment, I changed the return type of the method to be a byte array instead of a list of objects and then used .NET Protobuf (very nice serialization library from Google Code) to generate the serialized array. When I did this, the response comes back to the client within 10 seconds. While this is a good work around, it still doesn't explain the original issue.

Comment: My assumption is (and has been) that for some reason my IIS server is taking forever to XML serialize the return when it is a large collection. That would explain why simply returning a byte array completely takes care of that right?  I still just don't really get why I don't get that delay at all on my local machine.

Comment: This is really strange. If I were in that situation I would probably end up trying to take a couple thread dumps during that delay and see what the thread handling the request was doing.

Comment: Actually, here is another suggestion. You can isolate just the serialization... I'll update my original answer with a code snippit in a couple minutes...

Comment: Well, I think we can scratch serialization. I plugged in your code block (which was a really good idea) and it only took 7ms to execute. The server environment is a two server web farm that sits behind an F5 load balancer. The delay happens on both servers but the fact that the IIS log timestamps completely correlate with the lag still makes me think that it's some obscure server setting or something more than the topology. Maybe I'll try the thread dump idea.